# Create Polygon with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, image, polygon

How can we create image like below with PHP  and store their coordinate in MYSQL database.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at OpenGIS extension ([Spatial data support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-extensions.html)) of MySQL, and PHP [GD2](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) extension.

**UPD:**

[OpenGIS Simple Features Specifications For SQL](http://www.opengis.org/docs/99-049.pdf) might be useful too.
Many database management systems support it.

Comment: Either GD2 or SVG, since it comes from vector data: http://code.google.com/p/phpsvg/  http://www.goat1000.com/svggraph.php

Comment: `SVG` is better than `GD2`, because removes server load. But it requires `HTML5` browser support.